# Load and instantiate class from jar in class search path

Tags: java, classpath, classloader

I am looking for a way to instantiate an object from a jar file in my class search path, i know the name of the class and the parent class it extends and the interface it implements, unfortunatelly i have not been able to find a solution so far.
So, suppose the following:

```
interface Modifier{
 //is basically just a flag
}
```

Then:

```
public class ModifierImpl implements Modifier{
 //some methods
}
```

Then:

```
public class CustomModifierImpl extends ModifierImpl{
    //some implementation here
    }
```

Those interfaces/classes are into a jar that i import dinamically in my project and then i would like to instantiate an instance of `CustomModifierImpl`

Since i know that the class `Class` is generic, i thought that something like so would be possible, but its not:

```
private Class<ModifierImpl> loadClass(String fullClassName) {
    Class<ModifierImpl> clazz;
    try {
        clazz= urlLoader.loadClass(fullClassName);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        return null;
    }
    return clazz;
}
```

I get a type mismatch when i do this, is there any other way i can achieve this? i would not like to work with an instance of `Class<?>` all around my program as i would probably need to do dozens of casts.

This will also not work:

```
private Class<ModifierImpl> loadClass(String fullClassName) {
    Class<ModifierImpl> clazz;
    try {
        clazz= urlLoader.loadClass(fullClassName).cast(clazz);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        return null;
    }
    return clazz;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to load class from .class file

```
File file2 = new File  ("c:\\myclasses\\");

// Convert File to a URL
URL url = file2.toURL();          // file:/c:/myclasses/
 URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};

// Create a new class loader with the directory
ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);

 // Load in the class; 
 Class cls = cl.loadClass("test.MyClass");
```

to get the class:

```
Class aClass;
ClassLoader classLoader = test.class.getClassLoader();
try {
    aClass = classLoader.loadClass(fullClassName);
   } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

once you have the class, you can instantiate it:

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(fullClassName);
Constructor<?> constructor = clazz.getConstructor();
Object result = constructor.newInstance();
```

Comment: this seems to have worked very well, thank you Guillaume